# Attach div to an exact position relative to an background (with size: cover)

Tags: html, css, background, size

I have a webpage with an background-image with **background-size:cover**.
Now I want to **overlay** this background-image with certain **div's**, which contain additional informations. These **div's** have to be at an exact position relative to the background image, even though I resize the broswer window.

That's just one attempt that didn't work.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="icon">
<div class="background picture_rendering"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.background {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); 
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('/images/icon.jpg');
    background-size: 5% auto;
    background-position: 227px center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

It should be something like the map-tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp But instead of links there should be icons.
I hope you understand :-)

Best regards,
The One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After realising that there is no general solution for the problem yet. (object-fit isn't widely support). 
I used the jquery-Plugin [imagefill.js](http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/).

CSS

```
.background {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://connect.homes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/200392710-0012.jpg); 
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: center center;
}

.container_icons
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.test
{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncX/qyL/ncXqyLdcB.png');
    background-size: 70px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 17% 49%;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/2.1.0/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/js/jquery-imagefill.js"></script>

    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="container_icons"><img class="test" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png" width="3869px" height="2574px" /></div>
    <script>
        $('.container_icons').imagefill();
</script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5oc63omz/21/) --> It doesn't work as good as on my webpage ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can create a parent or wrapper element which would have the background image and then place all the elements like icons etc inside this and do all your positioning etc. So I've  created this for you:

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif) no-repeat; 
    width: 145px;
    height: 126px;
    position: relative;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.icon1 {
    background: green;
    top: 20%;
    right: 10%;
}

.icon2 {
    background: red;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon icon1"></div>
    <div class="icon icon2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j5cgt22z/

So each icon is positioned inside the container, the planets need to use `position:absolute` to float them around in the container space but the container needs to have `position:relative` so they are positioned in relation to their parent http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

You can then use z-index on each position:absolute icon to stack each icon so the higher the z-index higher up the stack.

Hope this helps

Comment: These are all good solutions, but the behavoir of the image in the background isn't like `cover`, more like `contain`.